# Select2 - add class to a specific option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select like this:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Volvo</option>
    <option value="Cat" class="red">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog" class="red">Dog</option>
    <option value="Mark" class="green">Mark</option>
    <option value="BMW" class="blue">BMW</option>
    <option value="Snake" class="red">Snake</option>
    <option value="Ferrari" class="blue">Ferrari</option>
</select>
```

I would like to mantain the same class on select2... looking the code I have seen tha there is no reference between the original select and select2 in the Dom so I can't find search and set...

```
<ul class="select2-results__options" role="tree" id="select2-mySelect-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-mySelect-result-gagv-Cat" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> 
        Cat 
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-mySelect-result-0987-Dog" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> 
        Dog
    </li>
    <li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-mySelect-result-Fax9-Mark" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false"> 
        Mark
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I tried to use the "id" of "li", but there is a parameter created by select2 and changes everytime.

I would like to mantain the same classes from standard select... any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by targeting a substring of the `id`

```js
var list = document.querySelector("ul[id*='select2']").children;
var numItems = list.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    var item = list[i];
    var className = item.id.split("-").pop();
    item.classList.add(className);
}
```

Comment: it works... but it's strange that a famous plugin like this didn't think a solution more simple.... Thanks for the support!